# Cannot install less on Centos 6.6 by npm (Error: failed to fetch from registry: less)

Tags: node.js, npm, less

I want to install less module on Centos 6.6 by npm, but I come across some problems.

executed command:

```
[dinghao@localhost ~]$ sudo npm install -g less
```

error log:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npm.taobao.org/less
npm http GET https://registry.npm.taobao.org/less
npm http GET https://registry.npm.taobao.org/less
npm ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: less
npm ERR!     at RegClient.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:140:18)
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:32:9)
npm ERR!     at RegClient.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:122:10)
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:132:9)
npm ERR!     at RegClient.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:225:20)
npm ERR!     at Request._callback (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:204:20)
npm ERR!     at self.callback (/usr/lib/node_modules/request/index.js:148:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:117:20)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.self.clientErrorHandler (/usr/lib/node_modules/request/index.js:257:10)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:95:17)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "less"
npm ERR! cwd /home/dinghao
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.36
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.6
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/dinghao/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: https://registry.npm.taobao.org/less ? R u using private npm modules hosted in npm cloud?

Comment: I see the response for that registry when i invoke it via Chrome. I think you may be behind a proxy / Low internet connection ?

Comment: You are use taobao npm registry, and i try it again, I install it successful. please remove `sudo` and install it again.

Comment: or you can try to install with this command: `npm install -g less --registry=http://registry.npmjs.org`, get package infomation from npm offical registry.

Comment: @Sathish  i can get the response from the registry <https://registry.npm.taobao.org/less>, but i get error by above command. In addition, my working context is on the vmware workstation 10. Is this causing the error?

Comment: @Stiekel according to your advice, i retry the command again, and it didn't work. i remove the keywords sudo. i came across another error:      npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/less'. maybe i don't have enough authority to make the dir.

Comment: @MatthewDing Yes, EACCESS means you don't have access. Can you curl the registry within the vm?

Comment: @Sathish :  **the command is:**    curl https://registry.npmjs.org  **the result is:**  
    <code>{"db_name":"registry","doc_count":244933,"doc_del_count":357,"update_seq":1717275,"purge_seq":0,"compact_running":false,"disk_size":1056764027,"data_size":882852045,"instance_start_time":"1441757780024492","disk_format_version":6,"committed_update_seq":1717275}</code>

Comment: i found some similar problem solution, whether if this problem can be caused by version differences between less and nodejs?